# How do I determine if a BlobClient is for a snapshot in Azure SDK12 in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am converting from Azure SDK 11 to 12 and I cannot find an equivalent of CloudBlockBlob.IsSnapshot() in the C# library.  How can I do the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `storage sdk12` cannot do this, because in the official documentation, there is no `Properties` and `Methods` to do this.

All operations on `snapshot` are as follows:

[image]

You can also refer to this documetation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet#methods

===============================**Update:**========================

In SDKv12, I did not find a way to directly judge whether the blob is `snapshot`, but you can judge by the uri. If it is `snapshot`, the flag will be included after the uri.

You can use this code:

```
var uri = blockBlobClient1.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

Console.WriteLine(uri);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: I lived and breathed those docs on Microsoft all weekend and couldnt find it either.  There has to be a way.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you have any other questions, please let me know!